# Using Switch object crashes the code Android

Tags: android

I have `Switch` and `Timer` objects that check that switch every 1 second.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  switchOnOff = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchOnOff);

  // more code...


  m_timer = new Timer();
  m_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
      public void run() {              
      if(switchOnOff != null && switchOnOff.isChecked() && m_TcpClient != null) {
          if (!m_TcpClient.IsSocketUp()) {
              switchOnOff.setChecked(false);   <---- the code crashes here            
                  }
              }
          }
      }, 0, 1000);
}
```

If all of those conditions are true, I want to turn off the switch but the application crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: whenever you say app crashes, always remember to post crash logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you try to work with View from a worker thread but that is forbidden in Android.
You should wrap in new Runnable and run it on ui thread, for example :

```
 @Override
  public void run() {              
  if(switchOnOff != null && switchOnOff.isChecked() && m_TcpClient != null) {
      if (!m_TcpClient.IsSocketUp()) {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
             public void run() {
                switchOnOff.setChecked(false);
          }
      }

              }
          }
      }
  }, 0, 1000);
```

}